# How to use Google Places API for Web Service in android?

Tags: android, google-maps

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?rankby=distance&location=LATITUDE,LONGITUDE&rankBy=50000&types=grocery_or_supermarket&sensor=true&name=NAMESEARCH&key=SERVER_KEY

how to use this link to return json format for the results, I already have an Server Key but it keep saying that "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key."

Answer (score 5):

The official way to integrate Google Places API is through the Android implementation. You could use the [PlacePicker](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/placepicker) which takes care the most but if you have a need that it doesn't fill, then you could integrate just the [Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete) to your own UI.

Having said this if you would insist using the service url directly in an Android app, then you would need to configure a Browser Key in the Google Developer Console.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't. Android has its own way to query places through the GooglePlayApiClient (read more [here](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/)). You still want to use the web service you need a server key. From the documenation

> Note: The Google Places API Web Service does not work with an Android
>   or iOS API key.

you can get the key [here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/get-api-key). Please, note that key has a limitation of 15k text searches per day. If you need more you will have to apply for a premium plane

Comment: it is Google Places API for Android have Nearbysearch ?

Comment: yes it does. I strongly recommend you to go through the documentation

Comment: I already read the documentation but there is no proper documentation about nearby places search for android programmatically

Comment: did you look into [this](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/placepicker) ?

Comment: yes. I just want to retreive all the places that match my search in the given radius in android.

Comment: then use the webservice, if it suits better your needs

Comment: but it keep saying "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key." to the response in my client.

Comment: did you create the key from this [link](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/get-api-key) ? A Server key?

Comment: Hey @Blackbelt I just now came across this answer of yours. But I have already implemented web service api in my android app. What are the pro's and con's in webservice vs using this library?

Comment: @therealprashant In the case of my company we weren't getting any results and an annoying message on logcat. Maybe things changed since then, but I doubt. I would stick with the Google Play Services if I were in you

Comment: You mean the webservice which I have already used or transitioned to the library wrapper?

Answer (score 1):

1. I want you to delete the current server_key.
2. Create a new Server_Key.
3. It takes 10 mintues to activate the server_key, otherwise you will get error_message "The provided API key is expired".

Now hit the url voila it works!!!