# Android google places API exceeded daily quota

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, android-volley, google-places-api

I am creating android app and I have to implement maps and places so, I have created new google places API and when I send request using volley to get placeId from latitude and longitude I get error which says

```
{"error_message":"You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API.","html_attributions":[],"results":[],"status":"OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"}
```

But it is working fine on postman so, how can I fix this?

P.S. I am beginner so please correct me if there is any mistake in my process.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe Google's terms of service is restricting use of Place API from client application i.e your android app. I also have seen this in other question's comment. (As Troy Perales also has mentioned)

For tutorials or example for implementing Google API click [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/fire-place/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex)
and [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/location-places-android/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0). These are Codelabs examples on implementing Google Places API.`enter code here`
And here's [Places Docs](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/intro)

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

When developing for Android, Google recommends using the Places SDK for Android (https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/intro) instead of the Places API (https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/intro) because it is free and has generous usage limits. See https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/usage.

Comment: thank you but this is new api just created how come it exceeded 2500 request? And as I have mentioned it is working fine on postman.
I can't find way to get placeId from Places SDK for Android so I used Places API.

Comment: There are a number of SO posts with your same experience:

- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40570594/using-google-places-web-service-in-an-android-app]

- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34521700/how-to-access-google-places-web-service-from-android-application]

- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35195516/how-to-use-google-places-api-for-web-service-in-android]

Looks like Google is forcing the usage of the Android SDK.

For Place ID, did you already try https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/Place.html#getId() ?

Comment: I tried reading docs but couldn't understand if there is example then it would be great help.

Comment: You were right that Google's terms of service is restricting this from being used in a client application (like in an android app).